# CAB Files MAKECAB.exe Way to store directory structure

Tags: directory-structure, cab

I was hoping someone could tell me if there is a way to store the directory structure of the files I want when creating a CAB File using makecab.exe?

Or if there are other utilities to do this and create a CAB file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it.  I am using CABARC which is out of the SDK and has a recursive option on the directory structure.